# Connecting to MySQL with PDO from another IP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

As you probably all know, not connecting to mysql on localhost or 127.0.0.1 is slow when connecting to another servers ip, because of network configuration and other things. I posted this question to ask how I can spee dup connecting to mysql on a different server faster, it currently takes more than a whole second to connect to mysql using my pdo in php shown below

```
<?php
$config = require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/include/config.php';

// PDO Connection
try {
    $dns = "mysql:host=".$config['database']['host'].";dbname=".$config['database']['name']."";
    $pdo = new PDO($dns, $config['database']['username'], $config['database']['password']);
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    exit('Unable to connect to the master database!');
}
?>
```

When using 127.0.0.1 it took not even 100 milleseconds, is there a way to get it back to that state, when connecting to mysql on another server? I use mysql on another server due to ddos attacks on my main server and the risk of data loss.

Comment: There are just too many possible things that could be causing this. Without being on site with the right tools all you are going to get from this question are _guesses_. Make sure that `$config['database']['host']` is an ip address and not a domain name and you will remove the DNS lookup, but that may not reduce your connection time by much

Answer (score 0):

The explanation for the trick "127.0.0.1 vs. localhost" is fairly simple: an IP address takes no DNS lookup. Thus, to reproduce the behavior for the another host, just use its IP address instead of domain name.

However, you have to be aware of the *network latency* of the remote hosts in general, which can be eliminated only by means of changing the host itself. Let me advise you to ping your remote host from local one and watch the network latency. If it's big - better try to find a hosting provider in the neighborhood area.

Comment: So there is no way to speed up connecting to another IP outside of your server?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can't get into such fast mode, but try adding PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT parameter in your PDO constructor:

$pdo = new PDO($dns, $config['database']['username'], $config['database']['password'], array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true));

Check: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Does that work even when using 127.0.0.1? or will it only speed up other server IP's?

Comment: Solely by my own experience, it speeds up a bit on both local and remote.

Comment: So, did any of this help you?